# Pentaho | Issue with CSV file to Table output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

I am working in Pentaho spoon. I have a requirement to load CSV file data into one table.

I have used , as delimter in CSV file. I can see correct data in preview of CSV file input step. But when I tried to insert data into Table Output step, I am getting data truncation error.

This is because I have below kind of values in one of my column.
"2,ABC Squere".

As you see, I have "," in my column value so it is truncating and throwing error.How to solve this problem?

I want to upload data in Table with this kind of values..

Comment: change the delimiter in your CSV file.

Comment: which delimeter should I use? I used , but it is not working..Values are getting shifted to next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

```
test.csv
--------
colA,colB,colC
ABC,"2,ABC Squere",test
```

See below the settings. The key is to use `""` as encloser and `,` as delimiter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @NileshPatil If this resolves your issue, please mark this as a correct answer and close this thread. Or if you feel something more is needed although this is helpful, you can upvote this answer and refine your question.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your help. Yes, issue is resolved  now.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the delimiter say to PIPE and also keeping data as quoted text like "1,Name" this will treat the same as 1 column